# Что будет если сделать sudo rm -rf/* от пользователя

Tags: linux, gentoo

Имеется несколько компов. Они объеденены в сеть. Вопрос : если я зайду на одном из них в юзера (обычного, не админа) и выполню "sudo rm -rf/*" то падёт вся сеть или только тот комп с которого производились действия?

Comment: вы не сможете ничего сломать, так как у вас прав нет

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, как именно объединены. Если просто сетевые кабели воткнуты и всё, то ничего с другими компьютерами не произойдёт, потому что связь файлов не налажена.

Comment: капитан очевидность подсказывает: будет выдано сообщение об ошибке «user in not in sudoers file».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, ответ

> Удалятся файлы и каталоги отовсюду, что примонтировано не в read-only
>   режиме.

слишком упрощённый. Настолько упрощённый, что скорее - неправильный. Существует большая и сложная проблема из многих частей:

1. В разных ФС права доступа понимаются по разному. И нет однозначного переноса прав доступа (например) Ext3 -> FAT32. Поэтому, если Вы монтируете ФС с FAT32 на папку, относящуюся к Ext3, то адекватно организовать перенос прав доступа просто невозможно.
2. В монтируемой ФС (скорее всего) права доступа будут прописаны по отношению к тем юсерам, для которых эта ФС **локальна**. А на Вашем компе будет сосвем другой список пользователей. Есть способы их согласования, но они не тривиальны. Если же мы будем говорить об ACL на двух разных хостах, тот тут всё ещё сложнее. Одно можно сказать уверенно - пользователь *root* на одном хосте, не имеет ничего общего с пользователем *root* на другом хосте (к которому принадлежит монтируемая ФС).

Поэтому, я бы уточнил ответ так:

Удаляться все файлы, по отношению к которым у вас есть права на запись, с учётом сложной передачи ID пользователя и группы и преобразования системы ограничения прав на обоих ФС.

Короче - всё очень сложно!!!

Answer (score 1):

Удалятся файлы и каталоги отовсюду, что примонтировано не в read-only режиме.

Comment: ...и на удаление чего у пользователя есть соответствующие права доступа

Comment: В вопросе фигурирует sudo без параметров. В результате выполнится команда от имени root. Редко встречаются дистрибутивы с ограничением у root, думаю это не тот случай.

Comment: Для локальных файловых систем да, а при монтировании по сети другое устройство может и отлупить с ошибкой доступа, так как оно ничего не знает ни про какое sudo

Comment: Да и для локальных файловых систем (ext4) есть `chattr +i`, после чего удалять не может даже root :)

Comment: странно на raspberry pi встретился со случаем, когда доступ к устройству (PWM) через su работал, а sudo пишет, что прав не хватает

Answer (score 1):

Будет ошибка:

```
rm -rf/*
rm: неверный ключ — «/»
```

Так как путь нужно отделять разделителем (обычно пробелом)